# What is the easiest way to set up an AP?

Tags: internet, hotspot

I just want to use my Pi as hotspot. What's the easiest* way to get there?

What I have:

- Raspberry PI B+
- [TP-Link TL-WN725N](http://www.tp-link.de/products/details/cat-11_TL-WN725N.html) Wifi adapter with Realtek RTL8192CU chipset
- A fresh [RASPBIAN JESSIE WITH PIXEL
  2017-03-02](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)

What I have tried that didn't work:

- https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/
- https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
- http://raspberry-at-home.com/hotspot-wifi-access-point/
- http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot

Until the upgrade to Jessie, I used the script provided by Raspberry-at-home at the bottom of the article ant it worked really well. Now nothing works again, sadly.

*definition of "easy": Any method that brings up a solution in a reasonable amount of time (<5h) with little to no additional Google problem solving.

Comment: Have you tried [this method provided on eLinux](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot)? It looks like it would work and seems "easy" to setup.

Comment: This question is more or less, "I've tried everything and none of it worked, what do I do?", to which the only logical answer is, "Give up."  It makes more sense, problem solving wise, to get into the details of *how* something *specific* you tried did not work so you can resolve the problem.  By analogy, if your car does not start tomorrow, do you buy a new car -- and then if it does not start the next day, buy another new car, ad infinitum?  Or do you try and figure out why the car won't start and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: @goldilocks This is basically it. I already did everything to try to solve the problem and this was my last hope. To keep the analogy, if you spent more time trying to repair your car than it is worth, you start looking for different solutions instead of trying to fix every little problem that comes up. I also maybe formulated the question the wrong way: I am not really looking for an _easy_ method, but for one that can be _reproduced_.

Comment: *"if you spent more time trying to repair your car than it is worth, you start looking for different solutions"* -> Definitely.  In this case, the smart solution would be to buy a completely different device, namely a consumer ready hotspot of some sort (these are not pricer than an rpi, either).   Beware of "have my pi and eat it too" ;) -- "I want to use the DIY device but I don't want to do it myself because I do not have the time and/or skills".  Extending the car analogy, there is a limit to what you can fix by asking people how online.  Not everybody wants or needs to be a mechanic.

Comment: For those who still have problems with a hotspot, https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/ works for me (using Raspbian Stretch and the official Raspberry Pi wifi adapter)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't want to leave this unanswered, so I found an old Pi B+ and an AP-Compatible WiFi dongle, and after trying a few times, finally found a way for this to work.

**Please try the following steps:**

*BTW, I typed full commands below so you can open this page on your Pi's browser (starting on step 2) and copy and paste on the Terminal*

1. [Download and run PiBakery](http://pibakery.org/download.html), enter your WiFi SSID and Password, and Write your SD Card.
2. Start up your Pi, *open this page on browser*, open Terminal, and type *or copy and paste*:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install hostapd udhcpd  
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.42.1
   ```

Then edit this conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/udhcpd.conf
```

So that it has the following:

```
start 192.168.42.2  
end 192.168.42.20  
interface wlan0  
remaining yes  
opt dns 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2  
opt subnet 255.255.255.0  
opt router 192.168.42.1  
opt lease 864000
```

Then edit this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/udhcpd
```

Comment the following line:

```
#DHCPD_ENABLED="no"
```

Then edit this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Comment the following lines:

```
#allow-hotplug wlan0
#wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Then create this conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Copy and Paste the following:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=PiAccess
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=PiPassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Then edit this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/hostapd
```

Uncomment and add conf file location:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Then enable IP Forwarding:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

Then edit this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Uncomment this line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then enable NAT:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Then edit this file one last time:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

And add the following line to the bottom of the file:

```
up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

Finally for the hotspot to start when the Pi boots:

```
sudo update-rc.d hostapd enable
sudo update-rc.d udhcpd enable

sudo reboot
```

Restart your Pi and once running, you should see from another computer the new WiFi network called "PiAccess".

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer and for mentioning PiBakery, but it did sadly not work on Jessy, Wheezy and the image provided by PiBakery.
Should I adapt the line "driver=nl80211" corresponding to my hardware?

Comment: Easiest might be to get a new WiFi dongle; but you could try a [special version of hostapd like this one](https://github.com/pritambaral/hostapd-rtl871xdrv).

Comment: I'll try that out later. The thing is, the dongle works well under Wheezy and supports everything it needs to so it really *should* work.

Comment: I retried it using the official wifi dongle. The hotspot works, but does not share internet now.